# Java HttpURLConnection only works on certain sites

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

```
package internet;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class internet {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.wikipedia.org");

        HttpURLConnection hc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int length = hc.getContentLength();
        System.out.println(length);
        InputStream input = url.openStream();
        byte[] binput = new byte[100000];
        input.read(binput);
        input.close();

        final String result = new String(binput);

        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

A strange thing happened. I can't get display the result and the length is -1. But when i use other url. For example, http://www.edwinlengzai.com. It works. Any Idea?

Comment: Is it possible that the websites are loaded in uniquely different ways, and as such they have different responses? Likewise, do you know if the HttpURLConnection is respecting the robots.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try in this way? address should be set as the site you want to read

```
    URL page = new URL(address);
    StringBuffer text = new StringBuffer();
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) page.openConnection();
    conn.connect();
    InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) conn.getContent());
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);
    box.setText("Getting data ...");
    String line;
    do {
      line = buff.readLine();
      text.append(line + "\n");
    } while (line != null);
    final String result = new String(text.toString());
```